# ¿Cual sería el problema en esta calculadora creada con React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

vi una calculadora creada con React en Github:
[Repositorio de la calculadora](https://github.com/AprendiendoFrontend/Aprendiendo-React/tree/master/react-calculator)

La descargué, y quiero ejecutarla, probarla, verla no se. Y no me deja, aparentemente hay un error en el archivo "app.js", que dice lo siguiente:

```
Unexpected token (14:2)
  12 |
  13 | ReactDOM.render(
> 14 |   <Provider store={store}>
     |  ^
  15 |     <CalculatorApp />
  16 |   </Provider>,
  17 |   document.getElementById('app')
```

El código completo del archivo **app.js**:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import {CalculatorApp} from './CalculatorApp'
import './app.css'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import calculatorAppReducers from './reducers/'

const store = createStore(calculatorAppReducers)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <CalculatorApp />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)

/* without redux
ReactDOM.render(
  <CalculatorApp />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
*/
```

Aclaro que en el **package.json** en la parte de dependencias no estaba el react-redux, pero lo instale y lo mismo sigue sin andar. Comentando la parte de Redux y descomentando la otra, tiene otros varios errores, por eso no opte por esa opción.

Comment: Cloné el repo, luego `npm install`, `npm start` e inicia ok la app, pero al ingresar a http://localhost:1234 me arroja [los siguientes erorres js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzfTi.png). Opinión personal, si ya de entrada te está dando problemas algo que supuestamente te debería ayudar a aprender react, creo que no es el mejor tutorial, no hay nada que asegure que corrigiendo esos errores no vaya a haber otros más adelante. Yo que tu, buscaría otro tutorial mas por ahí que hay varios. Saludos

Comment: @AlterLagos Hola, no era un tutorial. En un grupo de fb, supieron subir ese repositorio hace bastante. Y fue algo como que pensé "bueno, cuando empiece aprender React lo vere mas a fondo a esta calculadora para entenderla" y bueno, esa era la razón. Muchas gracias por contestar!